# How to use qdel with multiple array?

Tags: ssh

I haven't been able to find a solution to my problem with qdel :

I have a range of array jobs like :

```
123456[0].pbs02
123456[1].pbs02
123456[2].pbs02
222222[0].pbs02
222222[1].pbs02
222222[2].pbs02
```

Let's say I wanna kill the following jobs : 123456[1].pbs02 , 123456[2].pbs02 and 222222[0].pbs02

I tried multiple solutions, like :

```
qdel 123456[1].pbs02  123456[2].pbs02 222222[0].pbs02
```

which doesnt work ("No Match"), even with only one job as argument.

```
qdel -t 1,2 123456[].pbs02 -t 0 222222[].pbs02
```

doesn't work either, it tells me that -t is mutually exclusive, can't use it more than once

The only thing that works is this :

```
qdel -t 1,2 123456[].pbs02
```

But I can't work on multiple job arrays in the same command.
Easiest solution would be to use it without -t, just by writing the array item I wanna kill, but for some reason it doesn't work, as I said above.

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple solution, just had to backslash all the characters related to the array.
So something like this works like a charm :

```
qdel 123456\[\1\].pbs02  123456\[\2\].pbs02 222222\[\0\].pbs02
```